# An example of compact diffeomorphism group?

Tags: differential-geometry, compactness, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact smooth manifold. Then we can endow the set of diffeomorphisms of $X$ with $C^1$ topology. Are there any examples when $\mathrm{Diff}(X)$ is compact (as a topological space)?

Comment: No, unless $dim(X)=0$.

Comment: Consider the case $X = \mathbb{R}^n$, then look at diffeomorphisms that are trivial off a small neighborhood of a point.

Comment: @anomaly: yes, indeed $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ embeds into $\mathrm{Diff}(X)$ for a smooth manifold $X$ of dimension $n$. Apparently, I was a little confused with my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very far from being compact, its Lie algebra is the set of vector fields which is infinite dimensional if $dim>0$ so it is an infinite dimensional Lie group.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Diffeomorphism_group